# Nuget pack suddenly failing

Tags: msbuild, nuget

After months of using Nuget Pack in PowerShell without a problem, it is suddenly failing every time.

These are the messages:

> Attempting to build package from 'MyProj.fsproj'.
>
> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '12.0' from 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin'.
>
> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\FSharp\Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.Targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration i s
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\GitHub\MyProj\MyProj.fsproj

I went into the `fsproj` file and found these elements:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(MinimumVisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.Targets" />
```

Looking in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\FSharp`, there is indeed a file called `Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.Targets`, but there is no such file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\FSharp`.

I tried to fix this issue by editing the fsproj file, and changing `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` to 14, but that did no good whatsoever.

Why is the auto-detection picking up MSBuild 12, not MSBuild 14? And more pertinently, why could this possibly have started happening after months and months of flawless builds?

I'm using the command `nuget pack MyProj.fsproj -properties Configuration=Release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just worked this out. I'd uninstalled Visual Studio 2015. It's still picking up an old version of MSBuild.

To solve this:

- I upgraded nuget from the command line using `nuget update -self`
- Then I installed the Visual Studio 14 Build Tools from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159